# Question on Connectedness of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I am reading Complex Analysis from this [book](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/complexorth.pdf). The authors state the following theorem without proof:

> **Theorem 1.12.** If any two points in $G \subset \mathbb{C}$ can be connected by a path in $G$, then $G$ is connected. Conversely, if
>   $G\subset \mathbb{C}$ is open and connected, then any two points of
>   $G$ can be connected by a path in $G$; in fact, we can connect any two
>   points of $G$ by a chain of horizontal and vertical segment lying in
>   $G$.

Later on, they go on to comment that

> *"Second part of Theorem 1.12 is not generally true if $G$ is not open. For example, circles are connected but there is no way connect
>   two distinct of a circle by a chain of segments that are subsets of
>   the circle."*

But this bothers me because circle in its own right is a path and any two points in the circle can connected using the circumferencial segment of the circle which again is a path.

Is it the case that two points in a set are connected by a path iff we can connect those points by chain of horizontal and vertical segment lying in that set? Intuitively it doesn't seem true.

Comment: Didn't you basically just say yourself that a circle is a counterexample?

Comment: The 'second part' is with respect to being able to choose a path consisting of a chain of horizontal and vertical segments. It is true when $G$ is open and connected, but if $G$ is only assumed to be connected (but not open), then it may not be true. The author then gives the circle as an example for when it fails (and remember the circle is 'not filled' -- that would be a ball or sphere).

Comment: @EricWofsey no I didn't because circle is connected but not open and yet any two points are connected by a circumferential path. Shouldn't we be looking for a set $G$ which is connected but not open and there are two points of G which are not connected by a path to show that theorem is not generally true?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri the authors state that "any two points of G can be connected by a path" But chain of horizontal and vertical segment are just one choice of path and isn't that what the "in fact" in the theorem trying to say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no “iff” anywhere.

Let's introduce a standard term and a non-standard term here, to make things more transparent:

Standard term: A set is *path-connected* if any two points in that set can be connected by a path in that set.

Non-standard term: A set is *segment-connected* if any two points in that set can be connected by a chain of segments in that set.

Obviously a chain of segments is a path, therefore any segment-connected set is path-connected.

Now the theorem makes the following statements about subsets of $\mathbb C$:

> - Every path-connected set is connected.
> - Every *open* connected set is segment-connected and therefore path-connected.

The comment then says:

> A non-open connected set need not be segment-connected

and gives a circle as counterexample.

Now you observed that the circle actually is a path, and therefore the circle is not just connected, but path-connected.

But neither the theorem nor the comment stated that path-connected sets need to be segment-connected. Indeed, the circle acts as a counterexample to that claim.

So being segment-connected is a strictly stronger condition than being path-connected.

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider a standard example in $\Bbb C=R^2$ of a connected set that is not path-connected: $G=\{(0,y):-1\le y\le1\}\cup\{(x,\sin\frac1x):0<x\le1\}$. The set $G$ is connected, it is not open, and there is no path in $G$ between the origin $(0,0)$ and the point $(1,\sin1)$ whether your path is a (finite) chain of horizontal and vertical segment, or not.